# Merging costum database with WP database

Tags: database, laravel, woocommerce

I have a database for my shop which I've written in Laravel and was wondering if it's possible to merge that database with Woocommerce or vice versa.
What I want to do is create a product in one site and be able to show it on my other site including pictures, description and ...
I looked into woocommerce database structure and saw that products are being saved in wp_posts.
Is it possible?

Comment: It's about accessing database if you have access to any database in your project you can show it's data, just consider it how you are going to create relations between that other database into your project database! like when someone orders a product you have to store a record for this order now where you want to save it and how you will get product from order? I guess if it's possible the best way is to save those products in your laravel projects database

Comment: @HassanShojaei thank you for you information.
what you described is possible to do but, since wordpress saves the product images in the same table (wp-post), it'll be kinda confusing to merge them both.
I don't think I can use the WP DB on my Laravel site because it'll be hard to change all the codes.
is it somehow possible to customize a code for once a product is created on laravel project, the code post the data on WP DB ?